# onEndReachedThreshold parameter in ReactNative Flatlist Includes header and footer components

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-web

I am trying to implement infinite scrolling using Flatlist in react native web. I am using onEndReachedThreshold={0.5} and onEndReached(to fetch more data) callback for the same.
But when the header and footer contents get larger, the onEndReached does not get called as onEndReachedThreshold includes the height of header and footer content.

As I have multiple pages with different header and footer content (some of them don't have footer content) for which I am using the same component, the constant value in onEndReachedThreshold won't work.

Is there a way to ignore the heights of header and footer content and include only the main listing height (Cards inside the listing have different heights depending on the content).

```
const AnimatedFlatList = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(FlatList);


        <Query
          query={listquery}
          variables={variables}          
        >
          {(data, fetchMore) => {
              return (
                <View style={style}>
                  <AnimatedFlatList
                    ListEmptyComponent={emptyComponent}
                    ListHeaderComponent={headerComponent}
                    ListFooterComponent={ footerComponent}
                    data={data}
                    initialNumToRender={20}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                    renderItem={({ item, index }) => (<listingCard item={item} index={index}/>)}
                    onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
                    onEndReached={() => { fetchMore({variables,
                      updateQuery: (prev, { fetchMoreResult }) => {
                        if (!fetchMoreResult) return prev;
                        return fetchMoreResult;
                      }
                    });
                    }}
                  />                  
                </View>
              );
            }
            return null;
          }}
        </Query>
```